# cannot partition the unallocated space, keep getting error

Tags: partitioning, diskpart

I'm trying to allocate this unallocated space and this is the error I get ... I cant delete or do anything .. this a 160 gb hard drive of mine which I'm not able to use .. can't install windows into it either .. keep getting this i/o device error.. the exact sentence is :

```
diskpart has encountered an error:The request could not be performed because of an i/o device error.
see system event log for more information
```

I will appreciate any kinda help 
thanks

Comment: What tool have you tried to use? Why you can't delete? Is that an external HDD? Please don't answer to this comment by another comment, but by editing your question, also please make your question more structured.

Comment: Where is the information from the event log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like either:

1. The cable is wearing a bit thin
2. The HDD has reached the end of its life

I would immediately advise you to check the cable. If no damage is present, then you know that the HDD has reached the end of its life, and it's time to get a new one. But really, I suspect that the HDD is dying/dead on the IO front

Comment: wish there was any solution